# Store SSIS package in named database?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a server hosting a number of different databases, all with the same structure, and a library of SSIS packages, some of which are common across the client databases and others are client-specific.

I'm aware that you can store packages in MSDB, but this is a shared store across the whole SQL instance - is it possible to attach a package to a specific database?

Comment: Is it a requirement that the SSIS packages get stored in MSDB? Storing packages in the file system might help organize as you need.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, when you store packages into the msdb, they are stored in specific instance's msdb. Either run `SELECT * FROM dbo.sysdtspackages90` (2005) or `SELECT * FROM dbo.sysssispackages` (2008) across all your instances and you'll determine which one is currently hosting your packages. If you are using folders, I have fancier version of these [queries](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/08/ssis-package-query.html) available.

What I believe you are observing is an artifact of the tools. There is only one instance of the [SQL Server Integration Services *Service*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137789%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). This service doesn't stop you from storing packages in specific instance, it just makes it a little more complex to do so. Or as I see it, by ditching the GUI (SSMS) you free yourself from the fetters of non-automated administration.

How do you push packages into the other named instances? You can either edit the service's .ini file as described in the above link and then reconnect to the Integration Services thing in SSMS or use a command line or query approach to managing your packages. We used the SSISDeployManifest in my previous shops with success to handle deployments. There is a GUI associated to the .ssisDeploymentManifest and you can use that to handle your deploys or you're welcome to work with the .NET object model to handle deployments. I was happy with my [PowerShell SSIS deployment and maintenance](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/08/powershell-ssis-deployment-and.html) but your mileage my vary.

Finally to give concrete examples for a command line deployment, the following would deploy a package named MyPackage.dtsx sitting in the root of C to named instances on the current machine and deploy them into the root of MSDB.

```
dtutil.exe /file "C:\MyPackage.dtsx" /DestServer .\Dev2008 /COPY SQL;"MyPackage"
dtutil.exe /file "C:\MyPackage.dtsx" /DestServer .\Test2008 /COPY SQL;"MyPackage"
```

I have an earlier version of my PowerShell script for [generating calls to dtexec](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2010/05/powershell-dtutil-ssisdeploymanifest.html) instead of using the object library directly.

Let me know if you have further questions

Comment: any full sample using powershell ?